# iOS Screen coordinates and scaling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, calayer

I'm trying to draw on top of an image in a CALayer and am having trouble with where the drawing shows up on different size displays.

```
func drawLayer(){
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let radius: CGFloat = 30
    let x = Thermo.frame.origin.x
    let y = Thermo.frame.origin.y
    let XX = Thermo.frame.width
    let YY = Thermo.frame.height
    print("X: \(x) Y: \(y) Width: \(XX) Height: \(YY)")
    circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.0 * radius, height: 2.0 * radius)  , cornerRadius: radius).CGPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3)
    circleLayer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    circleLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    circleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 0, 192);
    self.Thermo.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    circleLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

That draws a circle, in the correct place ... for an iPhone 6s. But when the enclosing UIImageView component is scaled for a smaller device, well, to clearly doesn't. I added the print() to see what the image size, and position was and ... well, it's exactly the same on every device I run it on X: 192.0 Y: 8.0 Width: 216.0 Height: 584.0 but clearly it's being scaled by the constraints in the AuoLayout manager.

So, my question is how can I figure out the proper radio and position for different screen sizes if I can't use the enclosing View's size and position since that seems to never change?

Here is the image I am starting with, in a UIImageView, and trying to draw over. 
[image: Base Image] Im of course trying to color it in based on data from an external device. Any suggestions/sample code most appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling `drawLayer()`? Move it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or `layoutSubviews()` if it's in a subclass of UIView?

Comment: It's not a subclass of UIView, not yet anyway. And calling setNeedsDisplay() causes the view to be re-drawn.

Comment: Calling setNeedsDisplay flags the layer as needing to be redrawn (i.e. you could call setNeedsDisplay three times in a row and it would only get redrawn once when pixels get pushed to the screen). You should move your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, as I suggested as that is called after the auto layout engine makes a pass, thus the last time `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called `Thermo.frame` will be correct.

Comment: So I have moved it to viewDidLayoutSubviews() as suggested. There is still some weirdness going on however. That DID help get the positioning (mostly) right, but since the scaling factor doesn't change regardless of the screen size -- until you get up to iPad devices -- it still looks odd because the circle is not the right size. Clearly iOS is scaling the image, but Thermo.image.scale returns 1.0 on all iPhone sizes. This makes the size wrong on different screen sizes, and the position subtly wrong as well (since the image is scaled).

Comment: You'll have to post a screen shot of what mostly right means and how you think it should be. I could be wrong but I'm guess Thermo.image.scale will tell you whether the image is @1x, @2x, or @3x if you only provide one image it will always return 1, hence why Earl Grey suggests you use `circleLayer.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` If you do your drawing in a subclass of UIView, you won't have to pay attention to scale unless you intend on doing very accurate drawing. Though I suspect your drawing being off is likely cause by something other than scale.

Answer (score 2):

CALayer and its subclasses incl. CAShapeLayer have a property

```
var contentsScale: CGFloat
```

From class reference :

> For layers you create and manage yourself, you must set the value of this property yourself based on the resolution of the screen and the content you are providing. Core Animation uses the value you specify as a cue to determine how to render your content.

So what you need to do is set the scale on the layer and you get the scale of the device from UIDevice class

```
circleLayer.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```